# How to get the results from raw expression in laravel mongodb?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I'm using Laravel and Mongodb. I want to get the results from a raw expression but failed.

I've tried to convert the results to an array. The result data shows but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Below is an example of my code:

```php
$result = DB::collection($tbl_name)->raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$match' => [
                'field_1' => [
                    '$regex' => 'some value here'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            '$group' => [
                '_id' => '$field_2',
                'total_amount' => ['$sum' => ['$toDouble' => '$field_3']],
                'total_count' => ['$sum' => 1],
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

This is the result that I get if I convert it to an array using `$result->toArray()`

```php
Array
(
    [0] => MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument Object
        (
            [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                (
                    [_id] =>
                    [total_amount] => 1000.0000
                    [total_count] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

I'm hoping there could be another way to retrieve the result. Thanks.

Comment: Have you used  like `$sql = str_replace_array('?',$query->getBindings(), $query->toSql());

// print
dd($sql);` ?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada it's not working. I've got `Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::getBindings()` error.

Comment: Are you using like `DB::collection($tbl_name)->toSql()`?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada Yes. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think it is because I'm using the raw function with aggregate, thus it return result as `Cursor` object.